# Почему блок не растягивается по отношению к вложенных блокам?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Не могу заставить **id="case_case2"** растянуться на высоту самого большого блока.

```css
.case_content2 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 730px;
 float: right;
}

.menu_left {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.menu_left a {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #3787cd;
}

#case_case2 {
 background-color: #185a96;
 padding: 20px;
 border-top: 4px solid #347aba;
 border-left: 4px solid #347aba;
 border-right: 4px solid #347aba;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #347aba;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.content_article {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 padding: 10px;
 line-height: 22px;
 border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
 <div id="case_case2">

 <div class="case_content2">
  <div class="content_article">
   <b>Во время строительства или ремонта наступает время, когда нужно выбрать радиаторы отопления.</b><br />
   <b>Какие лучше?</b> – обычно спрашивают покупатели у специалистов. На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Каждый тип радиаторов имеет как свои преимущества, так и свои недостатки. Поэтому вместо вопроса, какие хорошие радиаторы отопления вы знаете, нужно выяснить какой тип радиаторов максимально подходит именно для вашей системы отопления. Для этого нужно знать вид отопления, величину рабочего и максимального давления в системе, температуру и уровень кислотности теплоносителя. А определившись с типом радиатора, подходящую модель подобрать уже не сложно.
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="menu_left">
  <a href="/">Алюминиевые радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Биметаллические радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Комплектующие к радиаторам</a>
  <a href="/">Рекомендации по выбору радиатора</a>
 </div>


 </div>
```

Comment: Если ответ помог, поставьте галочку слева от ответа, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы блок `case_content2` был внутри `case_case2` задайте для `case_case2`:

```
case_case2 {
  min-height: someValue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Выложите из `case_case2` меню `menu_left`. И потом заменить `width` на `100%`:

```
.case_content2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

Рабочий пример: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4sn2ykx/)

Второй вариант: [JSFiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/NikitaSmith/uvu04ypz/)

Answer (score 1):

Логично, ведь вложенные блоки у вас имееют float, т.е. находятся в другом потоке.

```css
.case_content2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 730px;
}
.menu_left {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu_left a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3787cd;
}
#case_case2 {
  background-color: #185a96;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 4px solid #347aba;
  border-left: 4px solid #347aba;
  border-right: 4px solid #347aba;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #347aba;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.content_article {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div id="case_case2">
  <div class="case_content2">
    <div class="content_article">
      <b>Во время строительства или ремонта наступает время, когда нужно выбрать радиаторы отопления.</b>
      <br />
      <b>Какие лучше?</b> – обычно спрашивают покупатели у специалистов. На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Каждый тип радиаторов имеет как свои преимущества, так и свои недостатки. Поэтому вместо вопроса, какие хорошие радиаторы отопления вы знаете,
      нужно выяснить какой тип радиаторов максимально подходит именно для вашей системы отопления. Для этого нужно знать вид отопления, величину рабочего и максимального давления в системе, температуру и уровень кислотности теплоносителя. А определившись
      с типом радиатора, подходящую модель подобрать уже не сложно.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_left">
    <a href="/">Алюминиевые радиаторы</a>
    <a href="/">Биметаллические радиаторы</a>
    <a href="/">Комплектующие к радиаторам</a>
    <a href="/">Рекомендации по выбору радиатора</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: дело в том что блок с текстом мне нужен именно с правой стороны

Comment: легко и как говориться одной кнопкой. смотрите.